# Why can't I pass two bool value into std::function?

Tags: c++11

I want to define a callback by using std::function, the definition like below:

```
typedef std::function<void (const std::string &, const std::string &,
    const bool, const bool)> Callback;
```

But it has a syntax error, what can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Show more code, and format it properly. You *can* pass arbitrary data into `std::function`-s!

Comment: it make no sense to have const parameter

Comment: How do you use the `std::function` object? Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and edit your question to include it, together with the actual (and unedited and complete) errors?

Comment: It is an IDE bug. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You should include functional, to use function:

```
#include <functional>
```